# install wordpress 4.7.5 but I cannot add new plugin or theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image]

After installing WordPress version 4.7.5  . I am unable to add any new plugin or theme.

I am getting this error on plugin addition section in WordPress admin:

*An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server's configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try support forums.*

How to fixed this issue, please guide me step by step?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `localhost` right?

Comment: I doing in real server but I not have coding because I click automatic install in website back-end. Now  I can't add new plugin or theme.

Comment: @Goong Did you check my code, by any chance?

Comment: @purvik7373 No change. How to can fix any way?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true);
```

Add above line in your `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when adding new theme(but not on adding plugin). In my case, this was happening because default http request timeout(5 seconds) was too short to load the theme contents. Solution was quite simple, I just needed to increase it. Here’s the [link](http://www.letmefix-it.com/2016/06/27/how-to-fix-unexpected-error-at-theme-search/) for detail. Please like the post if this solves your problem. Good Luck!